# div outer borders

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div header that extends the entire length of the page, but I keep getting a small white outer border on all divs so that the entire page has a thin white border around the outside. I'd like for the divs to extend to the very edge.

I've tried a few different css options but none seemed to have worked. E.G (Not all at once)

```
div
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:0;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like the default margin/padding on the body. Some browsers uses margin, some (Opera) uses padding, so set both:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Ah didn't realise it had to be in the body section! Thanks, worked perfectly!

Comment: +1 ....if you're ever unsure, open up developer tools and check its parent element.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should be using some form of css reset or normalization. I'd check out [this one](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/), because it's by the master genius of css resets himself, Paul Irish.